# Changing Array buffer in 'jspdf'

Tags: jspdf

Everytime I try to generate a pdf and take the hash of array buffer then hash is changing everytime.

I don't understand why a hash is changing if the content is not changing.

```
  async function generateHash(x) {
    const hash = sha256(x);
    return hash;
  }
  async function genPdf() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.setFontSize(12);
    doc.setFont("helvetica", "bold");

    // Add information
    doc.text("ID:", 20, 10);
    doc.text("Name:", 20, 20);
    doc.text("Product Name:", 20, 30);
    doc.text("Quantity:", 20, 40);
    doc.text("Price:", 20, 50);
    doc.text("Location:", 20, 60);
    doc.text("Time:", 20, 70);
    doc.text("Buyer:", 20, 80);

   
    doc.setFont("helvetica", "normal");

    // Add values
    doc.text("1000", 80, 10);
    doc.text("AA", 80, 20);
    doc.text("A", 80, 30);
    doc.text("100", 80, 40);
    doc.text("100000", 80, 50);
    doc.text("a", 80, 60);
    doc.text("10:00 AM", 80, 70);
    doc.text("Jane Smith", 80, 80);

    const generatedPdfContent = doc.output("arraybuffer");
    const hash = await generateHash(generatedPdfContent);

    console.log(hash);

  }
```

I think that the array buffer is changing every time but how can it change for same content